# C# Serialization with control over Attribute and Element without System.Serialization?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, serialization, .net-4.0

I need to transform quickly some object into an XML string. If my project would not been in Silverlight, I would simply use the `[Serializable]` attribute with `[XmlElement]` and `[XmlAttribute]`. Unfortunately, this is [not available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee321573.aspx) in Silverlight. I can't use `DataContract` because it [does not give](http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/03/07/xmlserializer-vs-datacontractserializer-serialization-in-wcf/) the control of if the property need to be attribute or element tag.

So, what is my other option? I can do manually the XML using Linq-To-Xml but is there anything else more fast?

Comment: `[Serializable]` has nothing to do with XML Serialization anyway. Look at using LINQ to XML.

Comment: Serializable as nothing to do with Serialization? really

Comment: `[Serializable]` has to do with "runtime serialization", not "XML Serialization". That's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use [`System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28VS.95%29.aspx) .

Answer (score 1):

In terms of performance, [`XmlWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) (fast, non-cached, forward-only) with self-implemented serialization is preferable.